# Irreducible representations of $SO(N)$

Tags: representation-theory, orthogonal-matrices

I'm looking for a reference/proof where I can understand the irreps of $SO(N)$. I'm particularly interested in the case when $N=2M$ is even, and I'm really only interested in the reps that come from taking exterior powers of $\mathbb{R}^{2M}$. Doing some numerical experiments, it seems like for general $M$ the following facts are true:

- $\bigwedge^m \mathbb{R}^{2M}$ is a real irrep for $m\neq M$.
- $\bigwedge^m \mathbb{R}^{2M} \simeq \bigwedge^{2M-m} \mathbb{R}^{2M}$ for $m\neq M$.
- $\bigwedge^M \mathbb{R}^{2M}$ decomposes into two irreps of the same dimension. These irreps are real when $M$ is even and complex-conjugates of each other when $M$ is odd.

Does anyone know how I can prove this? I think proving $\bigwedge^m \mathbb{R}^{2M} \simeq \bigwedge^{2M-m} \mathbb{R}^{2M}$ seems straightforward, but I am not sure how to prove irreducibility for any of these cases.

Comment: Everywhere you write $SO(2M)$ inside an exterior product you mean the defining representation $\mathbb{R}^{2M}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that's right, I'm considering the group $SO(2M)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^{2M}$

Comment: But that's not what you wrote! Anyway I fixed it.

Comment: I believe all of these are true but the only argument I have in mind for irreducibility is a slightly tedious highest weight argument. The second and third bullet points involve the Hodge star, which sends $\wedge^m$ to $\wedge^{2M-m}$ and splits $\wedge^M$ into two eigenspaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator

Comment: @Qiaochuyuan I definitely agree that the Hodge star operator gives the isomorphism/splitting of the irreps! Still stuck on actually proving these are irreps.

Comment: It would be better if I just knew a reference where the argument is written down but basically the idea (for the highest weight argument) is to first split the rep into weight spaces (eigenspaces) for the action of the maximal torus $T = SO(2)^m$, argue that any invariant subspace must be a sum of weight spaces, then pass to the action of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2m)$ which contains operators that move between weight spaces. If you've ever seen the classification of finite-dimensional irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ this should be basically familiar.

Comment: For irreducibility you can restrict to the alternating group.... When $k \ne M$ the space $\Lambda^k \mathbb{R}^{2M}$ decomposes as a direct sum of two irreducible $A_{2M}$ representations (corresponding to hook partitions), and then you can just check that $SO(2M)$ doesn't preserve these subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also take a look at "Representation Theory of Semisimple Groups" by Knapp. The details are given in Chapter IV, §5, Examples 3 and 4.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I think! I have to ponder this and @QiaochuYuan's answer, but this is definitely a more direct reference so probably more helpful.

Comment: By the way, I needed this reference for a physics paper, so if you'd like to be in the acknowledgements, send me a message with the name you'd like to be acknowledged under.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I found a reference: this is worked out (over $\mathbb{C}$ but the result over $\mathbb{C}$ should imply the result over $\mathbb{R}$) as Theorem 19.2 in Fulton and Harris' *[Representation Theory: A First Course](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387974954)*. Fulton and Harris do it by restricting to a copy of the symplectic group which is not what I expected.

Comment: I saw this reference, but is it obvious that the result over $\mathbb{C}$ implies the result over $\mathbb{R}$? Naively, if you restrict to a subgroup you could have more irreps than before, since subspaces that were mixed by the original group could be not mixed by the subgroup.

Comment: I'm also worried about using the Lie algebra to get the irreps of the Lie group. $SU(2M)$ is simply connected, so this works, but $SO(2M)$ is not simply connected. It seems like studying irreps of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2M)$ would give the irreps of $spin(2M)$ instead of $SO(2M)$.

Comment: @Jahan: 1) The result over $\mathbb{C}$ implies the result over $\mathbb{R}$. In general you can check that if a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on a real vector space $V$ such that the representation of $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathbb{C}$ on $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is irreducible, then the original representation must also be irreducible.

Comment: @Jahan: 2) This is also not a problem. You can check that if a connected Lie group $G$ acts on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ then $V$ is irreducible as a representation of $G$ iff it's irreducible as a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. We aren't classifying all representations here, just checking whether particular representations are irreducible, so the existence of the spin representations doesn't matter here.